# Erro ao usar API's da Google para rodar a partir do Android 2.3 (API Level 9)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estou desenvolvendo um *app* que irá rodar a partir da versão 2.3 do *Android (GingerBread - API Level 9)*. Porém, ao tentar adicionar as dependências do *Firebase* e do *Google Admob*, surgiu o seguinte erro ao tentar sincronizar:

> ```
> This support library should not use a different version (25) than the compilesdkversion (18)" na linha compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
> ```

Ao trocar `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'` por `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'`

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4] C:\Users\leand\.android\build-cache\e914e1341a896ecd664487a87a8e07281927ee66\output\AndroidManifest.xml
> Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage
> ```

Adicionei `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>` ao *AndroidManifest* conforme sugestão do próprio erro, mas a mesma mensagem continua aparecendo ao tentar sincronizar.

**Trecho do build.grade(Module: app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.black.flash"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

A versão 10.0.0 da *Google Play services* é a última a dar suporte à versão 2.3(API Level 9) do Android.

A versão 10.2.4, aquela que está a utilizar, requer API Level 14 como mínimo.

Você tem duas possibilidades para manter a compatibilidade da sua aplicação à API Level 9.

1. Usar a versão 10.0.0 da *Google Play services*.
2. Usar múltiplos APK's para suportar os dispositivos com API Level inferior a 14

Referências:

- [Google Play services and Firebase for Android will support API level 14 at minimum](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html).

Comment: Ótima dica. A opção 2 acredito ser a melhor para não limitar futuras evoluções do app, mas tem o ônus de se manter 2 aplicações. Talvez uma abordagem de multiprojeto possa atenuar essa gestão.

Comment: A ideia é utilizar um único projecto e usar `productFlavors` para gerar mais de uma APK.

Answer (score -1):

Adicione essa tag no seu AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="25" android:minSdkVersion="14"
      tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl"/>
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).

**OBS:** Lembrando que isso não garante que a library irá funcionar corretamente no seu app usando API menor que a especificada pela library. É preciso fazer testes pelo emulador com a API menor e colocar os devidos tratamentos e/ou mesmo bloquear a execução do código da library caso dê problemas nos testes usando:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
// Rode o código usando a library
} else {
// Rode o código sem usar a library
}
```

Sugestão:

Altere essas linhas do seu build.gradle conforme abaixo:

```
compileSdkVersion 25

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Sempre bom trabalhar na última versão da API e bibliotecas de compatibilidade.

Comment: O AP quer rodar a aplicação no Android 2.3(API Level 9) ou superior. Usar `android:minSdkVersion="14"` só permitirá rodá-la a partir da API Level 14.

Comment: Olha o que fala a documentação oficial (link que eu postei): "Por padrão, na importação de uma biblioteca com um valor de minSdkVersion maior que o arquivo de manifesto principal, ocorre um erro e não é possível importar a biblioteca. Para fazer com que a ferramenta de combinação ignore esse conflito e importe a biblioteca, mantendo o valor menor de minSdkVersion do aplicativo, adicione o atributo overrideLibrary à tag <uses-sdk>.". Esse override seria apenas para a library especificada no manifesto.

Comment: Isso é verdade, mas apenas irá eliminar o erro. Não garante que a aplicação irá funcionar sem problemas em versões inferiores à 14.

Comment: Concordo, onde a library for usada no app tem que ser testada na API baixa e colocado os devidos tratamentos se der problemas. Esqueci de mencionar isso na minha resposta.

Comment: Neste [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html) do Android Developers Blog é dito explicitamente que essa abordagem não irá funcionar.